# Avoid NullPointerException on JNI VM Startup

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, jvm, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

**EDIT:
 As  apangin pointed out in the comments, the assumption, it was an NPE is wrong.**

I am working on a bigger project, that made it necessary to use a JVM, which is called from c++ code. This is the method to create the JVM:

```
jvm_holder jvm_holder::create_jvm(std::vector<std::string> options) {

            /*
             * args args that produce the behaviour:
             *      {
             *          std::string("-Djava.class.path=./Assistant-0.1.0.jar"),
             *          std::string("-Xrs"),
             *          std::string("-XX:+UseAltSigs") <- this is not useful on linux, we know but we tried it anyways 
             *      };
             */

            if (nullptr != jvm){
                throw internal_exception("If you get this message during development, please read up on the usage of the JVM Holder!");
            }

            jvm_holder main_holder;

            JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

            JavaVMOption *opt = new JavaVMOption[options.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++){
                opt[i].optionString = (char *) options[i].c_str();
            }
            vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8; 
            vm_args.nOptions = (int) options.size();
            vm_args.options = opt;
            vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
            jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **) &main_holder.env, &vm_args);
            delete opt;
            if (rc != JNI_OK) {
                jvm_exception("Can not start JVM.");
            }
            return main_holder;
        }
```

Now, everytime the this code is executed (which is exactly once, when the program starts), there is an internal NullPointerException during the setup of the JVM. This NPE is handled inside the JVM and not really a big deal for the process itself.

BUT: Every process in the process group gets a SIGSEGV. I understand that this is the normal mechanism for the JVM to detect a NPE.

Now, there are some problems, that come with this method:

1. Another JVM, that is in the same process group also handles the NPE.
2. Whenever one of us uses the GDB, the process is suspended, which is really annoying. We could make the GDB ignore the signal, but we consider this to be a bad idea, since it means a problem in any other part of the project.
3. We fear that this leads to problems later in the project.

Now, we did not figure out why there even is this NPE, but is there a possibility to either turn off signal based NPE handling or avoid whatever leads to this startup problem? I can not imagine, that this never bothered  anyone, since it is the third time we came across the problem in only a few months and this time, we can not simply stop using the JNI.

Best regards

Comment: How do you know there is an internal NPE? Do you have an exception stack trace?

Comment: I've read this somewhere else (I do not remember where), and additionally, the other JVM in the process group also reacts to a NPE. In the end it is an educated guess.

Comment: OK, I suspected this was not NPE, but now I'm sure it is not. HotSpot JVM [deliberately generates SIGSEGV](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/68758c5ab0c1/src/cpu/x86/vm/vm_version_x86.cpp#l259) at startup to check certain CPU features. There is no switch to turn it off. I suggest skipping SEGSEGV in gdb altogether, because JVM uses it for its own purpose in many cases.

Comment: well, crap... but thank you!

Comment: @mko Signal chaining does not help with SIGSEGV.